# Reload/Refresh section of page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML page that is broken into DIVS. Each div contains a particular section. Only one section gets displayed at a time. My requirement is to refresh each section when as it moves from one section to another. Please take a look at the code at below URL,

http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/VE4sU/15/
jquery code,

```
    // overwrite $jScroller to supply asynchronous callback when end has been reached:
    $jScroller.scroll = function() {
      for (var i in $jScroller.config.obj) {
           if ($jScroller.config.obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
               var
                obj        = $jScroller.config.obj[i],
                left       = Number(($jScroller.get.px(obj.child.css('left'))||0)),
                top        = Number(($jScroller.get.px(obj.child.css('top'))||0)),
                min_height = obj.parent.height(),
                min_width  = obj.parent.width(),
                height     = obj.child.height(),
                width      = obj.child.width();

               if (!obj.pause) {
                   switch(obj.direction) {
                    case 'up':
                     if (top <= -1 * height) {
                         $jScroller.stop();
                         obj.child.css('top','0px');
                         manager.callback();
                         break;
                     }
                     obj.child.css('top',top - obj.speed + 'px');
                    break;
                    case 'right':
                     if (left >= min_width) {left = -1 * width;}
                     obj.child.css('left',left + obj.speed + 'px');
                    break;
                    case 'left':
                     if (left <= -1 * width) {left = min_width;}
                     obj.child.css('left',left - obj.speed + 'px');
                    break;
                    case 'down':
                     if (top >= min_height) {top = -1 * height;}
                     obj.child.css('top',top + obj.speed + 'px');
                    break;
                   }
               }
           }
      }
    }

    $jScroller.start = function() {
        if ($jScroller.cache.timer === 0 && $jScroller.config.refresh > 0) {
            $jScroller.cache.timer = window.setInterval($jScroller.scroll, $jScroller.config.refresh);
        }
    };

$(document).ready(function() {

        function SectionManager() {
            this.delayShortList = 15000;
            this.marginShortList = 12;
            this.currentSection = null;
            this.sections = $("#content .section");
            this.numSections = this.sections.length;

            this.transition = function (){
                    //SCROLLER CODE STARTS HERE....
                     $jScroller.config.refresh = 100;
                    // Add Scroller Object
                    $jScroller.config.obj = [];
                    $jScroller.add(
                        "#content .section.active .activityTbl"
                        ,"#content .section.active .activityTbl > table"
                        ,"up"
                        , 3
                    );
                    // Start Autoscroller
                    $jScroller.start();
                    $jScroller.cache.init = true;
                    //SCROLLER CODE ENDS HERE....
            };
            this.onFullCycleCompleted = function () {
                //window.location.replace(window.location.href);
                alert("the following will trigger a page reload (UNLESS run from within jsfiddle): window.location.replace(window.location.href);");
            };
            this.callback = function () {
                if (this.currentSection >= this.numSections-1) {
                    this.onFullCycleCompleted();
                };
                this.currentSection = (this.currentSection != null)
                    ? (this.currentSection + 1) % this.numSections
                    : 0
                ;
                $("#content .section").removeClass("active");
                var $currentSection = $("#content .section:eq(" + this.currentSection + ")");
                $currentSection.addClass("active");
                var itemCount = $(".activityTbl table.data tr", $currentSection).length;
                if (itemCount < this.marginShortList) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        manager.transition();
                    }, this.delayShortList);
                } else {
                    this.transition();
                };
            };

            this.run = function(){
                this.callback();
            };

        }

        manager = new SectionManager();
        manager.run();

});
```

The page basically displays Activity1 then Activity2 and so on. My requirement is to refresh the contents as it moves from Activity1 to Activity2 before displaying it. That way I can have most current information from the server.

Comment: this sounds like you want us to do your work for you.. where are you stuck at exactly? that's too much code you got up there.. you should try to isolate your problem and simplify it

Comment: The current code refreshes the page after end of entire cycle. But I do not know how to refresh the page in between sections. So in above code line this.callback = function () {
                if (this.currentSection >= this.numSections-1) {
                    this.onFullCycleCompleted();
                };  refreshes page after entire cycle. I am not sure how to tweak it so instead of entire cycle it refreshes after each section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While one section is active (in the `this.callback` function or in `.run`) add an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get your data

```
    $.ajax()
```

for the current+1 section and [fill it into the html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) of the section

```
    $(yoursectiondata).html()
```

**Edit:** The ajax call addet to the callback function would be something like this:

```
    var nextSection = this.currentSection + 1;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your data source or update_script.php',
        data: {'section_id': nextSection },
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#content .section:eq(" + nextSection + ")").html(result);
        }
    });
```

**Edit:** Since you insist to do a page reload and not just retrieve the section. The only way to do this is to tell your server at which section you are at, so that the newly served page will know from which section to continue. This is definitely the less elegant option, so I want to encourage you to use the ajax call. However, this is how it could work:

1. After a section finishes, you call and pass the `sectionid` through GET to the server

   ```
   var nextSection = this.currentSection + 1;
   window.location.replace('your-page-url/page.php?sectionid=' + nextSection)
   ```
2. At the server you get your section id and pass it back with the new page (serverside you integrate it into the table, or reorder the sections, whatever), something like this in php:

   ```
   //get the section id
   $sectionid = $_GET['sectionid'];
   // for example integrate the id somewhere on the page
   echo "<input type='hidden' id='sectionid' value=".$sectionid." />"
   ```
3. When the DOM loads in a browser the sectionid can be retrieved with jQuery

   ```
   var sectionid = $("sectionid").val();
   ```

And now you can use this `sectionid` in the jQuery script to display the sections contents.

However, if you do this after each section, you might as well just load one section at a time on the page, since you wont be showing more at a time. I don't see why you would prefer this approach over an ajax call. But here you go.

**Last edit:**

Here is my final solution. No, you can not just reload the page after each section and magically expect it will know from where to start. But with ajax you can call the same html page and extract the next section and put it into the current pages DOM.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'your-page.html',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                   content1 = $(result).find("#content .section:eq(" + nextSection + ")").html();
                   $("#content .section:eq(" + nextSection + ")").html(content1);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                   $("#content .section:eq(" + nextSection + ")").html("error refreshing");
                }
            });
```

[I put this code also in action on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VE4sU/18/)

With such a solution you can also take out the `onFullCycleCompleted` reload, since the sections are always up to date.

Comment: Martin thanks for your reply. I tried above code but the scrolling stops working. Also, there is not a direct URL through which I can call data source. Is it possible to reload the page?

Comment: the code does not break the scrolling ... I tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/VE4sU/16/ Here i call a nonexistent script ... and cause it gives an error ... it just fills the second section with the html of the current section ... to illustrate how it works. Instead of reloading you can just ajax-call the same page, but probably it shouldn't be so hard to make a separate small script that just returns the required section - what is your data source? You could also just reload the page ... but then you need to tell it from which section to start, so that it does not start over.

Comment: Yes that is right. If possible I would like to reload the page and take it to a different section and not start over again.

Comment: Can you show me how to reload the page and take it to a different section after reload?

Comment: i just extended the answer to include the alternatives.

Comment: thanks for the update but all I have is a simple HTML page. I will not be able to use any scripting languages on the page. Is it possible using only jquery/ajax to refresh the page after every section and redirect it to correct section?

Comment: but how will anything change if it is just a html page on the server? you can also just call this html in a ajax call and take out just the right section, i can show you if you give me a link.

Comment: actually there is a script that keeps on generating this page. And I just need to refresh this page so that it gets the most updated version of itself from the server. Is it not possible to add jquery code in jsfiddle so that the page refreshes everytime it moves to a different section. Currently it does update but at the end of the cycle and in between sections.

Comment: Ok, now I wrote the code for you and added it to the answer. This will work now exactly the way you wanted. And now you do not need to reload the page on the end of the full cycle.

Comment: So while it is running Activity1, if I make any updates to my HTML section of Activity3, it should display the updated version of my text when it shows up Activity3, right?

Comment: yes! That is right. You only need to put your html url into the ajax call and it should work like a charm =)

Comment: Because I tried testing it on local HTML page and it did not work. I will try it on the server and see if it works. I appreciate all your help so far.

Comment: it works in the fiddle example that i supplied ... if you havent changed it much it should work. some browsers (eg. chrome) don't allow local ajax calls, so it wont work calling a file on your computer.

Comment: ok I tested it and it works on the server. Thank you so much @Martin. I appreciate all your help with this. I am going to mark this as an answer and also going to upvote it:)>